# Oracle How to count total number of rows inserted in a plsql block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to count no of inserts I make into the database

The below query returns one(1) although 2 rows did update

```
begin 
   Insert into APPLICATIONS (ID,ALIAS,NAME,STATUS) 
        values (1000000386,'BB','Branch Budgets','I'));
   Insert into APPLICATIONS (ID,ALIAS,NAME,STATUS) 
        values (1000000257,'TIME','Timesheets','I'));
   dbms_output.put_line('No Of rows'||sql%Rowcount);
 end;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
dbms_output.put_line('No Of rows'||sql%Rowcount);
```

This will give you total number of rows updated by **last** statement. So even if you have 10 insert statements this way, you will always get `1` as `sql%rowcount`.

Either use 2 output statements, one each after `insert` statements, or use a variable and add number of rows updated to it, and then display it at last.

```
declare
    v_count integer;
    begin 
        v_count:=0;
       Insert into APPLICATIONS (ID,ALIAS,NAME,STATUS) 
            values (1000000386,'BB','Branch Budgets','I');
        v_count:=   sql%Rowcount;
       Insert into APPLICATIONS (ID,ALIAS,NAME,STATUS) 
            values (1000000257,'TIME','Timesheets','I');
        v_count:= v_count+ sql%Rowcount;
       dbms_output.put_line('No Of rows '||v_count);
     commit;
     end;
```

OR
 If you are inserting data to same table, use a combined `insert` statement like this.
This will return 2 rows.

```
begin    
    INSERT ALL 
        into  APPLICATIONS (ID,ALIAS,NAME,STATUS) 
             values (1000000386,'BB','Branch Budgets','I')
        into  APPLICATIONS (ID,ALIAS,NAME,STATUS) 
             values (1000000257,'TIME','Timesheets','I')
    SELECT * FROM dual;         
    dbms_output.put_line('No Of rows '||sql%Rowcount);
    commit;
    end;
```

Comment: Thanks - my network was down therefore I took long to respond

Comment: No problem. Also please accept the answers for previously asked question, if you have not done it already. In case if was not answered properly, please comment on the answer so it could be looked at. Thanks!